# Linux Bible 10th Edition: why -exec cp can't copy files even with super user privileges?

Tags: permissions, fedora, find

I read *"Linux Bible 10th Edition"* at 130 page. Exercise №7:

> Create a **/tmp/FILES** directory. Find all files under the **/usr/share**
> directory that are more than 5MB and less than 10MB and copy them to
> the **/tmp/FILES** directory.

My command looks like `find /usr/share -type f -size +5M -size -10M -exec cp {} /tmp/FILES \;`. I ran it like usual user and got

```
cp: error copying '/bla/bla' to '/lol/kek': Input/output error find: '/usr/share/bla-bla': Permission denied
```

After that I tried to ran it as super user and got error (without `Permission denied`):

```
cp: error copying '/bla/bla' to '/lol/kek': Input/output error
```

Please, explain me, what the reason of that errors even when I run it as super user. Thank you.

P.S. Please, explain why command with of `-exec` should have empty `{}`?

Comment: Check mount options of target FS, obviously even root cannot copy to readonly  FS

Comment: @user1700494 that produces a different error, “Read-only file system”.

Comment: What's the actual filename? `/bla/bla` is not even in `/usr/share`, is that intentional? Same for `/lol/kek` which is not in `/tmp/FILES`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

“Input/output error” indicates a low-level I/O error (`EIO`) either while reading a source file or while writing a target file. This means you have a problem with your storage; `dmesg` will give you more information.

Such errors are not related to privileges or permissions, which is why running `cp` as root doesn’t make them disappear (unlike the “Permission denied” error).

[Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/389705/86440) explains the use of `{}` with `-exec`.